# Unable to locate an element ->right click on it->hover over to the context menu to export report-Using Selenium Webdriver for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

[image of DOM][1]```

```
//<tr id="hdr_506dbfe0db0e1c9018490ad4e2961934" class="" style="">
<th aria-hidden="true" class="" style=";"></th>
<th name="search" class=" list-decoration-table" style=";">
    <span class="sr-only">Actions</span>
</th>
<th name="number" class="text-align-left list_header_cell list_hdr" 
glide_label="Number"></th>
```

headers = browser.find_element_by_name('number')
#This errors out as an exception

header2= browser.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
#this returns the element id, so don't know if the required info is being pulled or no

```
Requirement-I need to find the element 'number' right click on it, to open the context menu and hover till the bottom of it, which opens up another context menu to export a report in .xlsx format.

The web page is completely dynamic so @id doesn't work as it changes at every session. I am using selenium webdriver for chrome.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated. 

I am pretty new to coding, so Pardon me if the way of asking the question is wrong. I will improve as per the guidance of the experts of the forum


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1MaI.png
```

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the DOM or else update the DOM info. Because few th tags doesn't have <>

Comment: Have added the DOM, appreciate your time for looking into the problem i have

Comment: Give it a try with this one ```//th[@name='number']//a[@role='button'] ```

Comment: Tried the solution provided, but that didn't work. Gives the same exception

Answer (score 0):

First, if `html attribute` like `@id` change at every session. You need to use `Xpath` instead.

Second, if this is dynamic web page, some html element only show and available when you perform some action. The solution here is you only need wait when element available by using `WebDriverWait` https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: I did try waiting for the page to appear, though by calling time.sleep(30) but it didn't help, also i have tried using xpath but that also didn't work for probably, i didn't do it correctly. I have shared the DOM though, i will try to use the xpath again and share what i tried. Thanks!!!